# DIV expanding over the DIV below

Tags: html, css

I just hit sth that appears to be a bug or at least a really weird feature of CSS/HTML.
Now, the problem is that i got three divs in a row, all inside a parent div.

The first and the second one are supposed to be text containers in a chat-like matter. The last one is supposed to be excluded and be a paging navigation.

On the very first page, that works fine. On every other page, **the last text container div expands over the navigation**. When using the Chrome developer tools, it shows me that the second div is only having its real size, while the background still expands over the navigation. But if i delete the navigation, the second text container resizes to its real size.
Also, when using

```
position:absolute;
```

it doesn't expand. Setting the position to relative explicitly didn't fix the problem and setting the background-color to sth else didn't change the white background.

I made you a quick demonstration under [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/3jypt/1/embedded/result/). 
**So the final question is**: Why does the second text div expand? Or doesn't it but it looks like it does?

//edit: As suggested in the comments, here is the raw CSS/HTML outside jsfiddle. I still don't think that's a good idea, but if you say so..

```
<div class="decoded_chat" pagenr="1" style="display: block;">
  <div class="decoded_user decoded_user_first" isme="0">

    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/4" target="_new" title="Profil aufrufen">

      <img class="decoded_user_avatar" src="http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=square">

      <div class="decoded_user_name">
        Zuckerberg
      </div>

    </a>

      <div class="decoded_msg_date">
        02.02.2014, 01:36 Uhr
      </div>
      <div class="decoded_msg">
        I will listen to the songs when I'm not so tired
      </div>
      <div class="decoded_msg">
        I don't know.. Possibly
      </div>
      <div class="decoded_user decoded_user_last" isme="0">

        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/4" target="_new" title="Profil aufrufen">

          <img class="decoded_user_avatar" src="http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=square">

          <div class="decoded_user_name">
            Zuckerberg
          </div>

        </a>

        <div class="decoded_msg_date">
          02.02.2014, 01:33 Uhr
        </div>
        <div class="decoded_msg">
          I've been ill all week.. Just haven't had time for much
        </div>
        <div class="decoded_chat_pager">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" pagenr="0" class="cloudview_msg_prev">
            « Vorherige Seite
          </a>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" pagenr="2" class="cloudview_msg_next">
            Nächste Seite »
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.chat_list {
    width:100%;
}
.decoded_chat {
    text-align:left;
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.cloudview_msg_next {
    float:right;
}
.decoded_chat_pager {
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:5px;
    text-align:left;
    width:95%;
}
.decoded_msg {
    margin-bottom:3px;
}
.decoded_user {
    padding:15px 10px;
    min-height:50px;
}
.decoded_user_last {
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}
.decoded_user_first {
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
}
.decoded_user_name {
    color:black;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.mychatmessage {
    background-color:#BFF2BF;
}
.decoded_msg_date {
    float:right;
    color:grey;
    margin-top:-30px;
}
.decoded_user_avatar {
    position:absolute;
}
.decoded_user_name {
    font-weight:bold;
}
.decoded_user_name, .decoded_msg {
    margin-left:64px;
}
table {
    text-align:center;
}
.flipped-180 {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter:"FlipH";
}
#detailopener, #return_to_msg, #return_to_cloud, #cloudview_delete {
    display:none;
}
.chat_list_names {
    color:grey;
}
.invi {
    position:fixed;
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    top:-2000px;
    left:-2000px;
}
.next_page_chat_list {
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:5px;
}
.last_page_chat_list {
    padding-left:5px;
    text-align:left;
}
.loadingtext {
    margin-top:7px;
}
#opener {
    position:fixed;
    left:25px;
    bottom:25px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
}
.dontdroponme {
    opacity:0.3;
}
#dropper {
    position:fixed;
    right:25px;
    bottom:25px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
}
.dropinfo {
    border-radius:7px;
    color:white;
    padding:5px 25px;
}
.dorpinfo img {
    width:48px;
}
.chatlist_button img, .decoded_user_avatar {
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #888;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.chatlist_button {
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #888;
    padding:5px;
    cursor:move;
    max-width:200px;
    margin:auto;
}
.ui-draggable-dragging {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
}
body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#3B5998;
    color:white;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:Calibri;
}
#innerbody {
    margin:auto;
    width:55%;
    text-align:center;
}
#innerbody_floater {
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: You need to post code to this question, not just a fiddle. HTML and CSS please.

Comment: I think there is an error in your code, there is a `</div>` in there that doesn't belong to anything, right before the last `<div class="decoded_chat_pager">`

Comment: @disinfor That are tons of code. Use the "Edit fiddle" - button to see all the HTML & CSS.

Comment: @JamesCameron per stackoverflow guidelines, you should also post code to the question in the event that the fiddle link disappears. That will make sure others can still see the question and answers even if the link is gone.

Comment: 34 lines of html (tabified) and 222 of css. You can post here, don't worry :)

Comment: Well, i pasted the tidied source into the post now. Hope we can now step to solving problems.

Comment: Did you try removing the `</div>` i mentioned? I tried it in your fiddle, and it worked, if I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah, i tried it, a tag mismatch was one of my ideas too. For me, it lowers the height of the second textbox but makes the navigation implode into it. Probably i got the wrong div, but jsfiddle marks some red, but removing them doesn't help. Adding a new **</div>** helps, but removes the div from the right parent.

Comment: If I understand correctly, would it help adding a `</div>` right before this code here `<div class="decoded_chat_pager">`? Take a look at this fiddle, is this what you're trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/3jypt/3/

Comment: Or perhaps this? http://jsfiddle.net/3jypt/4/

Comment: The first fiddle doesn't change the problem except for the changed css to make the navigation black and therefore visible. The second one is exactly what i just refered to as bad solution, as it removes the div from the parent div. Using dirtymarkup.com it appears as if the markup is right. //edit: I just discovered that removing the "Vorherige Seite" solved the problem.. Now i just need to know why..

Answer (score 0):

Copy from http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is html:

Comment: I see no possible solution to the occuring problem that's suggested by this answer.